# Angular 5.2.3 data-bind to data attribute with hyphen in name

Tags: angular, data-binding, custom-data-attribute

Using Angular 5.2.3.

It is my understanding that this is valid HTML

`<div data-automation-for="howdy"></div>`

However when it try to data bind to it like this

`data-automation-for="{{day.date | dateFormat:'MMMM'}}"`

I get the following error

`Can't bind to 'automation-for' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. 
("<div style="display: inline-block" 
    [ERROR ->]data-automation-for="{{dateContext | dateFormat:'MMMM'}}">")`

Upon searching for this i found the following two potential solutions

`attr.data-automation-for="{{day.date | dateFormat:'MMMM'}}"`

and

`[attr.data-automation-for]="day.date | dateFormat:'MMMM'"`

However they both error too. It appears these solutions aren't handling the extra hyphens.

Now i realize i could be completely mistaken and extra hyphens are not valid but i haven't found anything stating that.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: mmm it looks like you're tryng to use a plugin in for data-automation-for .. i think it is not well included in your module ir something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [minimal StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vicouw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for you.

Main take-away: You were probably misinterpreting [the documentation of the *date* pipe.](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

```
<div [attr.data-automation-for]="dateContext | date:'MMMM'">
```

Note: Interpolation (using a variable via *{{varName}}*) is only used outside of other HTML tags.